# How to set build environment variables to use Clang as part of NDK?

Tags: android-ndk

The [latest NDK release](http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history.html) r11 says:

> We strongly recommend switching to Clang.

How do you this in practice when using the NDK to build open source libraries like OpenSSL and you need to set all the usual environment variables like `CPP`, `CC`, `CXX`, etc...?

All I see in `llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/` is `clang` and `clang++` but no `cpp` or `ld` tool, etc... contrary to what's in `arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin` which has every tool possible under the sun.

Are we supposed to mix and match? i.e. use `ld` and `cpp` from `arm-linux-androideabi-4.9` while `clang` from `llvm`?

[Update] For reference, here's my configuration for using the r10 NDK:

```
API_LEVEL="18"

HOST="arm-linux-androideabi"

export ANDROID_NDK="$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle"

export NDK_PLATFORM="$ANDROID_NDK/platforms/android-$API_LEVEL/arch-arm"
export NDK_TOOLCHAIN="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/$HOST-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64"

export CPP="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-cpp --sysroot=$NDK_PLATFORM"
export CC="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-gcc --sysroot=$NDK_PLATFORM"
export CXX="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-g++ --sysroot=$NDK_PLATFORM"
export LD="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-ld --sysroot=$NDK_PLATFORM"
export AR="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-ar"
export RANLIB="$NDK_TOOLCHAIN/bin/$HOST-ranlib"
```

Comment: Why not use [the makefiles from the AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/openssl/+/master) (with whatever modifications you need)? That way you can select the toolchain by setting `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION`.

Comment: Is there any instructions anywhere on doing it this way? Cross-compiling is usually about just calling `./configure && make` while overriding `CC` and friends. I'd rather keep doing it the "standard" way.

Comment: No instructions as far as I know. But if you're familiar with Android makefiles it's not that difficult. I've done this for OpenSSL in a project because it fit nicely with all the other native modules in the project which were built with `ndk-build`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, when using clang, it falls back to using some of the normal gnu binutils from the normal gcc toolchain. (The clang/llvm environment is getting a linker of their own, lld, but I believe the builds in the NDK still just uses the gnu binutils version).

Contrary to the gcc toolchains, there's only one llvm/clang toolchain in the NDK, which can target all the necessary arches. This also means that you need to pass parameters to it to tell it what you're intending it to compile for.

For your build script, you should be able to replace at least CC and CXX with the following:

```
export CC="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"
export CXX="$ANDROID_NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++ -target armv7-none-linux-androideabi -gcc-toolchain $NDK_TOOLCHAIN"
```

For CPP, AR and RANLIB, you're probably best off just using the same as you are now. For LD, if you currently are referring directly to the low level `ld` tool, you should probably stick to that. If you're linking using the gcc frontend, you should switch that to using clang instead. But in that case, the scripts would probably be using `$CC` for linking instead of `$LD` anyway.

Comment: Really, you can use GCC's preprocessor (`CPP` tool) with Clang compiler?

Comment: How would I change the environment variables to use GCC or Clang for linking instead of `ld` directly? Is there any benefit either way?

Comment: Well, I guess it depends on what the preprocessor is used for in the build system. In most cases, the GCC/clang frontend invokes the preprocessor by itself, so `$CPP` is only used if the build system for the library wants to manually preprocess a file for some reason - in the vast majority of cases, it isn't done at all. If you use GCC's preprocessor but later compile it with clang, you can of course run into cases where it checks for some GCC/clang feature macro, which mismatches with the compiler.

Comment: In the cases where `$CPP` really matters, you can maybe use `clang -E` instead of `cpp`. But exactly what to do depends a little on what the library's build system does with it - in most cases, it's not used at all.

Comment: If you want to use GCC or clang for linking instead of `ld`, you would simply use `gcc` or `clang` instead of `ld`. Again, I would guess that most library build systems don't use `$LD` at all. If you change `ld` into `clang` or `gcc`, you would probably need to change the library build system as well, since when using `ld`, you manually need to specify a lot more details that `gcc` fills in when using that for linking. For your case, try setting `LD = false` or something such and see if it breaks building, if not, the variable is not used for your library at all.

Comment: (That is, if switching from `ld` to `gcc` or `clang`, you would need to omit the details that `gcc` fills in, like CRT startup routines and such. But if the library build system really wants to use `ld`, it probably does that for a reason that it wants to do something more non-standard, and there's little point in switching it to `clang`. And if you're building static libraries, the linker isn't used at all, except for possibly some configure tests.)

Answer (score 5):

An alternative way to do this is to use `build/tools/make_standalone_toolchain.py`. That will build a full toolchain directory where you can directly invoke clang without having to worry about managing `-gcc-toolchain` and `--sysroot` yourself.

EDIT: Updated to refer to the new tool and removed the section of warnings since the problems there should all be fixed now.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html; they've added a make_standalone_toolchain.py script that's probably easier to use in Windows.

Comment: "They" is actually me :) I've updated my answer to account for it now. Thanks for the reminder!